# Update image selected via a confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a grid of images that I want to make a selection from and update the value with the selected image. Before doing so I hope a prompt that just checks if you do want to update or to cancel / dismiss.

What do I need to do to update "this.backGroundUrl" in the method below with the new selected image?

Image grid:

```
    <v-col
      v-for="(asset) in assets"
      :key="asset._id"
      cols="4"
    >
      <v-img
        :src="getThumbnail(asset)"
        @click="confirmDialog = true"
      />
    </v-col>
```

Confirm component:

```
<ConfirmDialog
  v-if="confirmDialog"
  v-model="confirmDialog"
  @cancel="confirmDialog = false"
  @confirm="updatedBackgroundImage()"
/>
```

Assets:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('assets', ['assets']),
```

Method:

```
 methods: {
    getThumbnail (asset) {
      return this.getMediaUrl(asset.thumbnailUrl)
    },
    getMediaUrl (url) {
      return process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + url
    },
    updatedBackgroundImage () {
      // this.currentConnect.backGroundUrl = ??
      this.confirmDialog = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you open the dialog, stash the URL.

```js
@click="showDialog(asset)"
```

```js
showDialog(asset) {
  this.theAssetToConfirm = asset
  this.confirmDialog = true
}
```

```js
updatedBackgroundImage () {
  this.currentConnect.backGroundUrl = this.theAssetToConfirm
  this.confirmDialog = false
}
```